# ssh from Linux to Windows cygwin

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I installed cygwin and configured openssh (ssh-host-config -y) on a Windows machine. Now from a Linux on the network I have a strange behavior:

- without .ssh (on the Linux), I successfully connect with password
- with .ssh (and my public key on the .ssh/authorized_keys of the Windows, I failed (and it doesn't ask me password):

> ssh -v M3D@ipinria029
>   OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
>   debug1: Reading configuration data /home/lionel/.ssh/config
>   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>   debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
>   debug1: Connecting to ipinria029 [10.0.31.29] port 22.
>   debug1: Connection established.
>   debug1: identity file /home/lionel/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
>   debug1: identity file /home/lionel/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
>   debug1: identity file /home/lionel/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
>   debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
>   debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
>   debug1: identity file /home/lionel/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
>   debug1: identity file /home/lionel/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
>   debug1: identity file /home/lionel/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
>   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7
>   debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7 pat OpenSSH*
>   debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
>   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>   debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
>   debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
>   debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
>   debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 2a:4a:bc:24:bc:9e:c6:17:bb:f1:54:e1:03:df:7e:d4
>   debug1: Host 'ipinria029' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
>   debug1: Found key in /home/lionel/.ssh/known_hosts:43
>   debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>   debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
>   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>   debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/lionel/.ssh/id_dsa
>   Connection closed by 10.0.31.29

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try moving your config and ssh_config files in ~/.ssh to a different location (temporarily)? I have a feeling that your config could be messing with it...

Other than that, could you please make sure that the authorized_keys in your windows is EXACTLY what is in ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub on your linux machine?

If that dosent work, try running ssh-keygen, and putting the id_rsa file in the authorized hosts. (this will overwrite ~/.ssh/id_rsa) I've never used dsa for ssh keys before, I've always used RSA.